# jQuery Hover Drop-Down-Menu Full Width Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a vertical menu in my Website. Now i need a dropdown system in some links.
I've see this example on the internet: http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/3018/
But i want a full width submenu. The Dropdown System of Sony is what I want.
Dropdown system by Sony: [Sony](http://sony.de)
I've always craetet a full width size dropdown menu.
My Code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/4. 
So what i want, when i hover the `content` so the submenu and again to the menu link which slidedown the submenu than the submenu should be there without some moves.

I hope I've explain what i want to do. I think it is possible but that overwhelmed my knowledge of JS and jQuery.

Can anyone tell me how to that?

Comment: What do you mean by **without some moves**?

Comment: One more question - Do you want exact output as the `sony.de` link given?

Comment: @Zword with "without some moves" i wanna say that the content have no animation.

Comment: I want this exact proportion to the drop-down menu of Sony, it need not be the same code. @Zword

Comment: So you dont want slidedown animation?

Comment: I want the slideDown animation for the Container by hovering the link. When you hover the Container and back to the link which Displays the Container then shouldnt the Container have the slideDown Effect again.

Comment: Check my answer and tell if any changes are needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML`

```
    <ul id="nav_menu">
    <li><a class="nav_menu_link nav">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu_link_drop nav">
        <a class="nav_menu_link">DropDown 1</a>
    </li>
        <div id="content1" class="content" style="display: none;">
            <ul style="padding: 20px; height: auto;">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li><br />
                      <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li><br />
                      <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li><br />
                      <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <li class="nav_menu_link_drop nav">
        <a class="nav_menu_link">DropDown 2 <i class="arrow down"></i></a></li>
    <div id="content2" class="content" style="display: none;">
        <ul style="padding: 20px; height: auto;">
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li><br />
                      <li><a href="#">Other Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

`jQuery`

```
var stop = true;
var hovered;
var timeout;

$('.nav').hover(
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        stop = true;
        hovered = this;
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if($(hovered).hasClass('nav_menu_link_drop')){
            $('.content').css('z-index',0);
            $(hovered).next('.content').css('z-index',5);        
            $(hovered).next('.content').slideDown(350);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.content').not($(hovered).next('.content')).slideUp(350);  
            },200);
        }
        else
            $('.content').slideUp(350);    
        },400);
    },
    function(e){
        stop = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!stop)
                $('.content').slideUp(350);
        },500);
    }
);

$('.content').hover(
    function(){
        stop = true;    
    },
    function(){    
    }
);

$('#nav_menu').hover(
    function(){
    },
    function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.content').slideUp(350);
        },200);
    }
);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/S7n2b/)

Comment: @Selfproblemmade I was just working with the first fiddle, but I can take a take a shot at the second fiddle tomorrow.  That is if your question still needs an answer.

Comment: jeah that will be great :)

Comment: This look exactly like i've imaged

Answer (score 1):

I have made **slidedown** in the fiddle which works exactly like `sony.de`:

## *[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kz8p/)(New)*

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <div id="mainMenu">
    <li class="menu1">Home</li>
    <li class="menu2">DropDown1</li>
    <li class="menu3">DropDown2</li>
    </div>
</ul>
    <div class="submenu menu2">
        <!--menu items-->
    </div>
    <div class="submenu menu3">
        <!--menu items-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#menu{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
#menu,#menu ul,#menu>ul>#mainMenu>li,#menu div{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#menu >ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:100;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:18px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFA500;
}
#menu ul>#mainMenu>li{
    padding: 29px;
}
#menu ul>#mainMenu>li:hover{
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
#menu .submenu{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var preClass="";
$('#menu>ul>#mainMenu>li').hover(function(){
    var curClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if(preClass!=curClass){
        $('.submenu[class*='+preClass+']').stop()
    .animate({'bottom':'0px'});
        $('.submenu[class*='+curClass+']').stop()
    .animate({'bottom':''+(-$('div[class*='+curClass+']').height())+'px'});}
    preClass=curClass;
});

$('#mainMenu').mouseleave(function(){
    preClass="";
    setTimeout(function(){
    if(preClass=="")
    $('.submenu').stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'});
    },350);
});

$('#menu').mouseleave(function(){
    preClass=""
    $('.submenu').stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'});
});

$('.submenu').hover(function(){
    preClass = $(this).attr('class').replace("submenu ","");
    $(this).css({'bottom':''+(-$(this).height())+'px'});
},
function(){
    if(preClass!=curClass){
    $(this).stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'});
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle with delay added like `sony.de`](http://jsfiddle.net/6kz8p/1/)

Comment: this ist that what i exactly mean, hover the content and hover the link which slidesDown the content. The container slides down again this shouldnt be so

Comment: Just clarify what do you mean by "content" , "link" & "container" in the above comment

Comment: yeah can you add a slideup(350)?

Comment: when you leave the container or the link.
Your function should run like that :/  http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/25/

Comment: look at the link, i've change the fiddle

Comment: @Selfproblemmade check the **New fiddle** in my answer.Tell if it works for you.If it works i will update my answer according to the new fiddle code

Comment: THIS LOOKS VERY GOOD the first Fiddle is that what i exactly want. Do you changed something in CSS?
And there is something wrong... :( When you hover a Dropdown link the and hover an other one, the container slidesdown, but when you do this again, there is no slidedown effect

Comment: @Selfproblemmade I am really not getting it clear when you want slidedown-slideup and when you dont.If its clear I can surely make the changes that will give the output you want

Comment: @Selfproblemmade you urself told in the first comment that the container shouldn't slide down again

Comment: Just tell me `On switch links do you want slide down?` - ***Yes*** or ***No***

Comment: It really looks like I want it, but when I go from one link to the other with the mouse, the content of the container swich and the container comes with a slide down, but if I do that again is no longer slide down there. **I want a slideDown and slideUp, YES!**

Comment: @Selfproblemmade but thats how its displayed in the very first fiddle

Comment: @Selfproblemmade ok i will try one more fiddle by what i have understood.Guess it will be the fiddle you want

Comment: the new fiddle was ok http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/Fg2p2/1/, but i want the slidedown effect just when you hover the other link not by the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49076/discussion-between-selfproblemmade-and-zword)

Comment: @Selfproblemmade check my new answer with new fiddles added

Comment: That's it man, i know you hate me :) because it took so long.

Comment: No @Selfproblemmade I dont hate u.Alwys glad to help

Answer (score 0):

### Check your needed code **[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6vqt/1/)**

### Download code file from [Box](https://app.box.com/s/25csv8nyjzr1aflcaigr)

#### HTML Code

```
<ul id="nav_menu">
    <li><a class="nav_menu_link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu_link_drop_1">
        <a class="nav_menu_link">DropDown 1</a>
    </li>
        <div id="content1" style="display: none;">  
            <ul id="file_menu">
                <li><a href="#file">File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#view">View</a></li>
                <li><a href="#insert">Insert</a></li>
                <li><a href="#modify">Modify</a></li>
                <li><a href="#control">Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="#debug">Debug</a></li>
                <li><a href="#window">Window</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <li class="nav_menu_link_drop_2">
        <a class="nav_menu_link">DropDown 2 <i class="arrow down"></i></a></li>
    <div id="content2" style="display: none;">
            <ul id="file_menu">
                <li><a href="#file">2 File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#edit">2 Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#view">2 View</a></li>
                <li><a href="#insert">2 Insert</a></li>
                <li><a href="#modify">2 Modify</a></li>
                <li><a href="#control">2 Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="#debug">2 Debug</a></li>
                <li><a href="#window">2 Window</a></li>
                <li><a href="#help">2 Help</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### CSS Code

```
* {   
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav_menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
#nav_menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.nav_menu_link {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    padding: 29px;
}
.nav_menu_link:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.nav_menu_link:hover .arrow.down {
    border-top-color: #FFF;
}

#content1:hover {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
}
#content2:hover {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
}
#content1, #content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: gray;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#file_menu {
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

#file_menu li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #302f2f;
}

#file_menu li a {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:5px 10px; 
    display:block;
}

#file_menu li a:hover {
    color: #F00880;
}
```

#### JQuery

```
var link1 = $(".nav_menu_link_drop_1");
var link2 = $(".nav_menu_link_drop_2");
var content1 = $('#content1');
var content2 = $('#content2');

$(link1).hover(
    function(){ 
        $(content1).slideDown(350);
    },
    function(){
        $(content1).slideUp(350);
    }
);

$(link2).hover(
    function(){ 
        $(content2).slideDown(350);
    },
    function(){
        $(content2).slideUp(350);
    }
);
```

Comment: This looks pretty good but when you hover the submenu and hover the link which slides down the submenu the container should be constant

Comment: Assuming you change .nav_menu_link_drop_1 and 2 to .nav_menu_link_drop, you could simply do $('.nav_menu_link_drop').next().slideToggle(); You don't need to write the same code two times.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with **only CSS**. Cleaner, simpler.

**Live demo here** : http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/3031/

Here's the modified CSS :

```
body {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
background-color: #333333;
}

#container {
    margin: auto;
}

#header {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 490px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#button {
    height: 32px;
    width: 184px;
    margin: auto;
}
#button:hover .file_menu {
    max-height: 100000px; 
    opacity: 1;
}
ul, li {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}

.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.file_menu {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.file_menu li {
    background-color: #302f2f;
}

.file_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px; 
    display:block;
}

.file_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #F00880;
}
```

Because you want it, here's the JS solution (cleaner than other answer):

```
var link = $("li[class^=nav_menu_link_drop]");

$(link).hover(

    function(){ 
        var content = $(this).next('div[id^="content"]');
        $(content).stop(true).slideDown(350);
    },
    function(){
         var content = $(this).next('div[id^="content"]');
         $(content).delay(350).slideUp(350);


    }
);
```

Is that doing the job ? http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/27/

Comment: i wanna the submenu in 100% width

Comment: It's 100% of window width there. Hmm no you're right, I guess I forgot to save : see it there > http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/3031/

Comment: Yep sorry, I thought I gave you the last version : http://jsfiddle.net/4jxph/3031/

Comment: but i want a slideDown(350) and slideUp(350) animation  by displaying the submenu!! When you add this you will get the bounty

Comment: It's easy with CSS transitions. I'm on it.

Comment: can you add a delay? after leaving the mouse

Comment: I think we can't do that in pure CSS.

Comment: So, ok i've tried your CSS in this: http://jsfiddle.net/t3ADE/
But this doesn't work.. :( Why?

Comment: Because it's not what I told you :) See there, no more JS : http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/24/

Comment: Why would someone need JS for that ?

Comment: Read the topic of my question and my request by adding a bounty

Comment: Edited my answer with a clean JS solution.

Comment: Bugs ? Which bugs ? By the way : you didn't ask clearly what you're looking for, you didn't post any code in your question (as requested by SO guidelines), so you should be happy someone answers you :)

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right you don't want the animation, for that simply set the animation time to 0. You dont need `.stop()` and you should consider using `.hover()` instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Here is a link: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Example:

```
$(link1).hover(
    function(){ 
        $(content1).slideDown(0);
    },
    function(){
        $(content1).slideUp(0);
    }
);
```

Here is your fiddle with updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/2/

EDIT: I just noticed but you have invalid html your `div`-tag is inside the `ul`-tag put it in your `li`... seriosly CHECK your markup... thats not the only wrong thing i noticed...

EDIT: Uhm... OK... maybe you should rethink your approuch, only because it works you shouldn't use invalid html

Comment: Look pretty good. But when i hover a link for the first time then should the content comes up with a duration of (350). When i hover the content and hover the link again then there should be no duration of slideDown or even no animation. I've add an animation duration, but this should only apply for the first time you hover a link: http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/4/

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/8/) do you mean something like that? But like I said you should check you markup and take a different approuch!

Comment: your fiddle code is the same you name in your answere, there is no difference. Please read the requirement of my Question, and on my comment to your answere.